# How can I XML Serialize a Sealed Class with No Parameterless Constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, sealed

I'm currently using an `XMLSerializer` to serialize a list of a class of my own.  One of the class's properties is an instance of a sealed class that does not have a parameterless constructor, so the XML Serializer refuses to serialize the class.  How can I get around this?  I need that property to be serialized.

Is there some way for me to specify how that class should be serialized?

We'd like to stay with XML; is there another XML serializer that I could use that would not have this problem?

Again, I apologize if this is a dupe, but I had no idea what to search.

[EDIT] To clarify, I don't have access to the source of the sealed class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible to do directly; `XmlSerializer` can't cope with classes that don't have a parameterless constructor.

What I normally do is wrap the parameterless class in another class that's compatible with XML. The wrapper class has a parameterless constructor and a set of read-write properties; it has a `FromXml` method that calls the real class's constructor.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public SomeClass SomeProperty { get; set; }

[XmlElement("SomeProperty")]
public XmlSomeClass XmlSomeProperty
{
    get { return XmlSomeClass.ToXml(SomeProperty); }
    set { SomeProperty = value.FromXml(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a private parameterless constructor?  That will work assuming you have access to the class's code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source.  It's part of an SDK.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` won't look at private members

Comment: In that case, I would try Tim Robinson's idea.  That was going to be my next suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ISerializable` on the containing class, then implement a custom serializer.

Comment: `ISerializable` is for `BinaryFormatter`. And even `IXmlSerializable` needs the ctor.

Comment: Ah.  Didn't know about the binaryformatter.  Couldn't you use a custom serializer and deserializer implementation to include property settings for the sealed object though?

Comment: not with XmlSerializer, no. Unless you write it all from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the xml, you *might* have some luck with `DataContractSerializer`. This doesn't offer anything *like* the same level of xml control, but it bypasses the constructor completely. And works for private types.

I might also ask: does it actually need to be xml? There are other serializers for things like json or protobuf that don't have the `XmlSerializer` limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IXmlSerializable`, `XmlSerializer` is too limited.

Comment: `IXmlSerializable` needs a parameterless constructor too.