# Error with xml serialization in c# - paramaterless constructor

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, biometrics

I am trying to serialse a fingerprint FMD to XML using the code below, but get an error:

> Error:  DPUruNet.DataResult`1[DPUruNet.Fmd] cannot be serialized
>   because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

```
  public void storePrint(DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion)
        {
                //store fingerprint as byte and insert to server------------
                 using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", false))
                {

                    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(resultConversion.GetType());
                    x.Serialize(myWriter, resultConversion);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Stored!");

                //------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        private void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check capture quality and throw an error if bad.
                if (!_sender.CheckCaptureResult(captureResult)) return;

                count++;

                DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(captureResult.Data, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI);

                SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "A finger was captured.  \r\nCount:  " + (count));

                if (resultConversion.ResultCode != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
                {
                    _sender.Reset = true;
                    throw new Exception(resultConversion.ResultCode.ToString());
                }

                preenrollmentFmds.Add(resultConversion.Data);
                //--------------------CALL METHOD
                storePrint(resultConversion);
                //
```

The class DataResult is being referenced, so I can not alter it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I XML Serialize a Sealed Class with No Parameterless Constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559744/how-can-i-xml-serialize-a-sealed-class-with-no-parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Cory, that is a useful answer, however in this example there is another way of serializing using

```
tempFingerPrint = Fmd.SerializeXml(resultConversion.Data);
```

this is specific to the Digital Persona SDK

Comment: Please tell me that the class type of tempFingerPrint

Comment: tempFingerPrint data type is string.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If you don't have access to the `DataResult<T>` class, then you might have to take a slightly different approach and wrap this class with a different, serializable one. You can find a full example here:

- [How can I XML Serialize a Sealed Class with No Parameterless Constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559744/how-can-i-xml-serialize-a-sealed-class-with-no-parameterless-constructor)

---

**Previous Answer**

The error is clear; you just need to add a parameterless constructor to the `DataResult<T>` class:

```
public class DataResult<T>
{
    // Add a default constructor (public visibility, no parameters)
    public DataResult() 
    {
        // You can still define a method body if you wish,
        // no restrictions there. Just don't do anything that
        // could jeopardize the (de)serialization.
    }
}
```

As for the implications of adding a default constructor, without knowing what

```
FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromFid(...)
```

is doing to create the `DataResult<Fmd>`, it would be impossible to know whether it would cause any issues.